# Cibonfire Template::render() like $this->load->view()

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, codeigniter-2, hmvc

Is it possible to get html source via `Template::render()` ? which look like `$this->load->view()` ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [render()](http://cibonfire.com/docs/files/libraries/template-php.html#Template.render) is as such:

```
public static function render( $layout = null )
```

And its return is `void` so simple answer no. It does not have an option to do so and does not return any output.

What you want to use if you want to get the HTML output is the [load_view()](http://cibonfire.com/docs/files/libraries/template-php.html#Template.load_view) method like so:

```
Template::load_view('you_view_name', $data, '', true, $html);
echo $html;
```

Note your arguments will differ from the above, so check the documentation linked to set them to what you want.

Comment: Thanks, you explain it -- well :)